# How to run multiple instances of a windowed program with GPU and capture its screen on Linux?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, nvidia, gpu

My goal is to create an environment for training machine learning agents to play a relatively lightweight computer game (that runs through Wine, but this should be irrelevant).

I would like to run as many instances of the game as possible while sending emulated inputs to them and capturing what the games show on the screen.

Right now I've tried running them through `xvfb` and capture the screen using `xlib` python bindings. This works, I am able to send inputs to the game and capture the screen, but xvfb does the rendering on the CPU, which makes the game run unacceptably slow.

An approach that behaves similarly to xvfb but allows the Nvidia GPU support would be perfect, but I couldn't find one.

The games don't need to run completely headless, but I need to be able to run them while also using other programs on my computer, so they need to run and have their screens captured while other applications are on top. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.